# HTML Select - How to Disable slide up/down animation in Microsoft Edge Browser

Tags: html, css, dropdown, microsoft-edge

Edge has a slide up/down animation dealio going on for `<select>`, I'd like to remove this animation but can't seem to find a solution other than using a custom dropdown instead. Wondering if anyone has figured out a way of disabling this animation?

`transition: none`
doesn't seem to do anything.

[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/bf28v06s/)

Comment: `If I went to an online form with a dropdown, and the site disabled the animation, I would be annoyed. I don't think this is such a good practice. Besides, the new Chromium Edge does not have this feature, and it is automatically replacing the Edge that has this feature.`

Answer (score 0):

You're right. You can't format a dropdown in a lot of ways. It's up to each browser to what dropdowns look like.

This should disable the slide animation:

```js
var coll = document.getElementsByClassName("collapsible");
var i;

for (i = 0; i < coll.length; i++) {
  coll[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
    this.classList.toggle("active");
    var content = this.nextElementSibling;
    if (content.style.display === "block") {
      content.style.display = "none";
    } else {
      content.style.display = "block";
    }
  });
}

function hide(element) {
  var x = document.getElementsByClassName("options");
  var i;
  for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
    x[i].style.backgroundColor = "white";
  }
  document.getElementById('content').style.display = 'none';
  element.style.backgroundColor = "#00ffff"
}
```

```css
.options:hover {
  background-color: #00dddd !important;
}

#buttons,
.options {
  cursor: pointer;
}

.options {
  border: 1px solid black;
  background-color:white;
}
#content {
  position:fixed;
  top:1em;
}
```

```html
<button id="buttons" class="collapsible">Click Me</button>
<div id="content" style="display:none;" onblur="this.style.display='none';">
  <ul style="list-style:none;">
    <li onclick="hide(this); document.getElementById('buttons').innerHTML=this.innerHTML;" class="options">option 1</li>
    <li onclick="hide(this); document.getElementById('buttons').innerHTML=this.innerHTML;" class="options">option 2</li>
    <li onclick="hide(this); document.getElementById('buttons').innerHTML=this.innerHTML;" class="options">option 3</li>
  </ul>
</div>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Mauris urna lorem, pulvinar ut eros efficitur, euismod viverra nunc. Sed at finibus odio, ut tempor.

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Mauris urna lorem, pulvinar ut eros efficitur, euismod viverra nunc. Sed at finibus odio, ut tempor.

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Mauris urna lorem, pulvinar ut eros efficitur, euismod viverra nunc. Sed at finibus odio, ut tempor.

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Mauris urna lorem, pulvinar ut eros efficitur, euismod viverra nunc. Sed at finibus odio, ut tempor.

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Mauris urna lorem, pulvinar ut eros efficitur, euismod viverra nunc. Sed at finibus odio, ut tempor.

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Mauris urna lorem, pulvinar ut eros efficitur, euismod viverra nunc. Sed at finibus odio, ut tempor.

</p>
```

You can just copy-paste that code. It's pretty ready.